# vue.jsのベースurlをhttp://localhost/develop に変えたい

Tags: vue.js, url

vue.jsでフロントエンドの開発をしており、
vue-cli-service build してdist配下をFlaskで動かす想定をしています。

vue-cli-service serveで動かすと、「http://localhost:80」で動作確認ができていますが、
最終的には「http://192.168.100.100/production」のように「サーバのIP/固定文言」をベースURLとして利用することを想定しています。

今回は、Vue-Routerを利用しているため、ホーム画面のURLは
「http://192.168.100.100/production/home」
ダッシュボードのURLは「http://192.168.100.100/production/dashborad」
のような形が理想です。

このような場合、Vue側でどのような設定が必要になるのかご教授頂けますでしょうか。
または、Vue側で何もする必要は無く（というか何もできない）Flaskで設定すべきなのでしょうか。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。

vue.config.jsを作成し、

publicPath: 'production'

と記載することでベースURLを変更することができました。